# How to convert flickrdataset to .npy file without extracting

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

```
!pip install kaggle
! mkdir ~/.kaggle
! cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/
! chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json

!kaggle datasets download -d arnaud58/flickrfaceshq-dataset-ffhq

from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
zipfile = ZipFile('/content/flickrfaceshq-dataset-ffhq.zip','r')
filenames = zipfile.namelist()
for names in filenames:
  data = zipfile.read(names)
```

Now, the data file here is of class bytes.

I am using Google Colab for the process. The file size is around 19 GB. So, it will take time to download the file and also, if I unzip the file directly into colab, it chokes the disk.

Also, my google drive space is no more than 15 GB

So, I was thinking of directly creating a code so that I can directly append each image array to a list and then use np.save(), I am thinking to create a binary file so that I can load images easily

Please, need your support

Comment: how do you expect to use less space than the already compressed file takes up? also consider the RAM you have available. if you have a lot of individual files (images?), save them individually, not as one big stacked numpy array.

Comment: yeah true..but is there a way to achieve what I am trying

Comment: impossible to say. presented situation is too vague.